# Insert new records with a field incremented by 1

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have a table, can be basically treated as collection of triples (id, key, sequence_number).
I need to sequentially number records with the same key. The table content after some time could be (ignoring id field, irrelevant):

```
("aaa", 5)
("bbb", 12)
("aaa", 6)
("ccc", 1)
("aaa", 7)
("bbb", 13)
```

The values must be consecutive, with no gaps in the sequence. How do I achieve that in a multiprocess environment in a cheap way (without locking everything, preferably without pessimistic locking at all)? 
Inserting values for the same key is rare (few entries with given key, hundred thousands of keys)

The alternative is to have a table (key, last_sequence_number) which would store latest sequence number for given key. This would be easy to update (pessimistic or optimistic locking). But maybe there's a way to use the previous approach efficiently?

edit:
I want to implement https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ef9W2whkCeE (around 6th minute). No, I might not need what I asked for above, but I'm wondering how to achieve it.

Comment: Oracle has sequences which would let you do this. It looks like db2 has sequences also but I don't know if they work exactly as you want.

Comment: Are you using DB2 for i, LUW, or z/OS?

Comment: DB2 for i has Encoded Vector Indexes, which could give you the max(seq) for any key value lightning fast.  But AFAIK they are not available under z/OS. @KevinPostlewaite, I think a different sequence would be needed for each key value.

Answer (score 1):

Given your requirements:

> The values must be consecutive, with no gaps in the sequence

I don't see why you still store values that don't comply: e.g. for `aaa` there's a gap and a duplicate value. Depending on why exactly you need that sequence number, you might be better off storing *guaranteed unique increasing* numbers *with gaps*, such as timestamps or regular SQL sequence values, neither of which would require locking, and *generate* gap-less numbering on retrieval using one of the OLAP functions: `row_number()` or `dense_rank()`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my mistake, it should be 5, 6, 7 for "aaa" (fixed). I need no gaps to implement eventual consistency. The idea is to pass from system A to system B current A's sequence number with every message. Then system B will be aware which (how many, which seq. numbers) messages were processed, which are missing - to guarantee that all messages are processed and in correct order. Added related link to the question.

Comment: I like this idea - I'd probably just add `ROW_NUMBER()` to a view.  Heck, if deriving it all the time turned out to be too expensive, you could materialize the view... although you'd probably need to do some sort of timed refresh + `UNION` or something.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse -- I doubt it will work in the OP's situation (now that we know the use case) as the sequence numbers seem to be needed _in the database_, not in the application.

Comment: If you feel it might be problematic, list what the downsides of deriving it with `ROW_NUMBER()` would be, or what other problems there might be in general.  To me, though, this sounds like an ideal solution.